# Yii form not submitting

Tags: php, yii

The following form does not submit. Am i missing something?

```
            <?php
            $form = $this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
                'id' => 'site-search-form',
                'action' => Yii::app()->createAbsoluteUrl('/moduleA/actionB'), //array('/moduleA/actionB'),
                'enableClientValidation' => true,
                'enableAjaxValidation' => true,
                'clientOptions' => array(
                    'validateOnSubmit' => true,
                ),
            ));
            echo $form->hiddenField($model, 'is_a', array('id' => 'is_candidate'));
            ?>
            <div class="blueline"></div>
            <div class="row">
                <?php echo $form->label($model, 'position_type'); ?>
                <?php echo $form->error($model, 'position_type'); ?>
                <?php
                $arr = CHtml::listData(PositionType::model()->findAll(array('condition' => 'status=1', 'order' => 't.order')), 'id', 'name');
                foreach ($arr as $k => $v) {
                    $arr[$k] = $v . ' Positions';
                }
                echo $form->dropDownList($model, 'position_type', $arr);
                ?>
                <div class="clear-float"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <?php echo $form->label($model, 'location'); ?>
                <?php echo $form->error($model, 'location'); ?>
                <?php echo $form->dropDownList($model, 'location', CHtml::listData(CitySector::model()->findAll(), 'id', 'name')); ?>
                <div class="clear-float"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="row buttons">
                <?php echo CHtml::submitButton(''); ?>
                <div class="clear-float"></div>
            </div>
            <?php
            $this->endWidget();
            ?>
```

Comment: "does not submit" is vague... And did you try to disable client/ajax validation ?

Comment: Any javascript errors?

Comment: no, it just stands there, no event is triggered

Comment: What does the rendered HTML look like?

Comment: Did u try with submitting a single div statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very likely that you have a validation error on an attribute that you did not render. In that case you could temporarily add a `<?php echo CHtml::errorSummary($model) ?>` somewhere to display all model errors.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the **`clientOptions`** parameter from the Yii Form Widget and try:

```
'clientOptions' => array(
    'validateOnSubmit' => true,
),
```

Answer (score 1):

For those who face the same problem, but the selected answer does not work. Make sure that you did not try to implement AJAX searching. AJAX searching will install a code to prevent the form from submit and will try to bring the data asynchronously. If that code failed or didn't work without giving javascript errors, you will be in a difficult situation. To check if AJAX code is being implemented or not, try to find this code in your view:

```
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('search', "
   ...
   $('.search-form form').submit(function(){
   ...
   return false; //<-- here's the trouble
```

Changing the line from return false to true shall make it work in non- AJAX way.